# Copy specific records to new table in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How i copy specific records from old_table to new_table at the time of creating new_table. (Through single command) in Oracle SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 INSERT INTO 'expense_incomes' (category_id,added_by,description,amount,date,status,type,created_at,updated_at)


SELECT expense_category_id,user_id,description,amount,date,status,'Expense',created_at,updated_at FROM 'expenses'");
```

Answer (score 1):

CTAS, probably (Create Table As Select), for example

```
create table new_table
as 
select * From old_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE table_A AS SELECT * FROM table_B
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table table1 (column names and types here)
insert table1 
select columns from table2
where... your filters here
```

Comment: Can i copy specific rows when creating new_table?

Comment: yes add the rules defining what you want to copy to your where clause - for example, where color='red'...